# coc.nvim doesn't work when I split a window in vim

Tags: vim, coc.nvim

*This is my first question on stackoverflow, If there is any mistake, please forgive me and tell me what mistakes I made.*

I used coc.nvim to automatically complete my golang source.
When I typing this

```
vim main.go
```

, it works normally, but after entering the command below in command mode, the highlight and code review no longer works.

```
:e main.go
```

I tried to find some command that make it works, but nothing was found.

Is there any command like this?

```
:CocEnableInCurrentSource
```

My coc-settings.json

```
{
  "languageserver": {
    "go": {
      "command": "gopls",
      "rootPatterns": ["go.mod"],
      "trace.server": "verbose",
      "filetypes": ["go"]
    }
  }
}
```

My .vimrc config:

```
syntax on
set number
set wildmenu
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set nocp " show line number
set ignorecase smartcase " ignore command caps
set ts=4 " tab account for 4 space
set mouse=a " click to locate cursor 

" color industry

" what's this??
" split screen
colorscheme onedark
highlight LineNr ctermfg=grey

hi Normal ctermbg=none
hi Terminal ctermbg=none
" It doesn't work.
" set guifont=JetBrainsMono-Medium

map sv :set splitright<CR>:vsplit<CR>
map sp :set splitbelow<CR>:split<CR>

map <up> :res +1<CR>
map <down> :res -1<CR>
map <left> :vertical resize-5<CR>
map <right> :vertical resize+5<CR>

" terminal
map <C-F10> :below terminal zsh<CR>

" Nerdtree
map <F3> :NERDTreeMirror<CR>
map <F3> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" Tagbar
map <F4> :TagbarToggle<CR>

" table change
map tu :tabe<CR>
map tn :-tabnext<CR>
map ti :+tabnext<CR>
noremap j k
noremap k j



call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" complete me plus
Plug 'prabirshrestha/vim-lsp'
Plug 'mattn/vim-lsp-settings'
Plug 'prabirshrestha/asyncomplete.vim'
Plug 'prabirshrestha/asyncomplete-lsp.vim'

" bottom status bar
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'

" indent-guides
" Plug 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'

" file tree
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on': 'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'

" tagbar in ctags
Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar', { 'on': 'TagbarOpenAutoClose' }

" golang complete
" Plug 'fatih/vim-go', { 'do': ':GoUpdateBinaries' }

Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}

"" nice theme
"Plug 'sonph/onehalf', {'rtp': 'vim'}
"set t_Co=256
"set cursorline
"colorscheme onehalflight
"let g:airline_theme='onehalfdark'
"let g:airline = {'colorscheme': 'onehalfdark' }
"

" auto complete (old)
" Plug 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'

let g:tagbar_ctags_bin='ctags'
let g:tagbar_width=30
autocmd BufReadPost *.py,*.go :TagbarOpenAutoClose


call plug#end()

" coc.vim
"
" Set internal encoding of vim, not needed on neovim, since coc.nvim using some
" unicode characters in the file autoload/float.vim
set encoding=utf-8

" TextEdit might fail if hidden is not set.
set hidden

" Some servers have issues with backup files, see #649.
set nobackup
set nowritebackup

" Give more space for displaying messages.
set cmdheight=1

" Having longer updatetime (default is 4000 ms = 4 s) leads to noticeable
" delays and poor user experience.
set updatetime=300

" Don't pass messages to |ins-completion-menu|.
set shortmess+=c

" Always show the signcolumn, otherwise it would shift the text each time
" diagnostics appear/become resolved.
if has("nvim-0.5.0") || has("patch-8.1.1564")
  " Recently vim can merge signcolumn and number column into one
  set signcolumn=number
else
  set signcolumn=yes
endif

" Use tab for trigger completion with characters ahead and navigate.
" NOTE: Use command ':verbose imap <tab>' to make sure tab is not mapped by
" other plugin before putting this into your config.
inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
      \ pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" :
      \ <SID>check_back_space() ? "\<TAB>" :
      \ coc#refresh()
inoremap <expr><S-TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<C-h>"

function! s:check_back_space() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction

" Use <c-space> to trigger completion.
if has('nvim')
  inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()
else
  inoremap <silent><expr> <c-@> coc#refresh()
endif

" Make <CR> auto-select the first completion item and notify coc.nvim to
" format on enter, <cr> could be remapped by other vim plugin
inoremap <silent><expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm()
                              \: "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"

" Use `[g` and `]g` to navigate diagnostics
" Use `:CocDiagnostics` to get all diagnostics of current buffer in location list.
nmap <silent> [g <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-prev)
nmap <silent> ]g <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-next)

" GoTo code navigation.
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
nmap <silent> gy <Plug>(coc-type-definition)
nmap <silent> gi <Plug>(coc-implementation)
nmap <silent> gr <Plug>(coc-references)

" Use K to show documentation in preview window.
nnoremap <silent> K :call <SID>show_documentation()<CR>

function! s:show_documentation()
  if (index(['vim','help'], &filetype) >= 0)
    execute 'h '.expand('<cword>')
  elseif (coc#rpc#ready())
    call CocActionAsync('doHover')
  else
    execute '!' . &keywordprg . " " . expand('<cword>')
  endif
endfunction

" Highlight the symbol and its references when holding the cursor.
autocmd CursorHold * silent call CocActionAsync('highlight')

" Symbol renaming.
nmap <leader>rn <Plug>(coc-rename)

" Formatting selected code.
xmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)
nmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)

augroup mygroup
  autocmd!
  " Setup formatexpr specified filetype(s).
  autocmd FileType typescript,json setl formatexpr=CocAction('formatSelected')
  " Update signature help on jump placeholder.
  autocmd User CocJumpPlaceholder call CocActionAsync('showSignatureHelp')
augroup end

" Applying codeAction to the selected region.
" Example: `<leader>aap` for current paragraph
xmap <leader>a  <Plug>(coc-codeaction-selected)
nmap <leader>a  <Plug>(coc-codeaction-selected)

" Remap keys for applying codeAction to the current buffer.
nmap <leader>ac  <Plug>(coc-codeaction)
" Apply AutoFix to problem on the current line.
nmap <leader>qf  <Plug>(coc-fix-current)

" Run the Code Lens action on the current line.
nmap <leader>cl  <Plug>(coc-codelens-action)

" Map function and class text objects
" NOTE: Requires 'textDocument.documentSymbol' support from the language server.
xmap if <Plug>(coc-funcobj-i)
omap if <Plug>(coc-funcobj-i)
xmap af <Plug>(coc-funcobj-a)
omap af <Plug>(coc-funcobj-a)
xmap ic <Plug>(coc-classobj-i)
omap ic <Plug>(coc-classobj-i)
xmap ac <Plug>(coc-classobj-a)
omap ac <Plug>(coc-classobj-a)

" Remap <C-f> and <C-b> for scroll float windows/popups.
if has('nvim-0.4.0') || has('patch-8.2.0750')
  nnoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-f> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(1) : "\<C-f>"
  nnoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-b> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(0) : "\<C-b>"
  inoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-f> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r>=coc#float#scroll(1)\<cr>" : "\<Right>"
  inoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-b> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r>=coc#float#scroll(0)\<cr>" : "\<Left>"
  vnoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-f> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(1) : "\<C-f>"
  vnoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-b> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(0) : "\<C-b>"
endif

" Use CTRL-S for selections ranges.
" Requires 'textDocument/selectionRange' support of language server.
nmap <silent> <C-s> <Plug>(coc-range-select)
xmap <silent> <C-s> <Plug>(coc-range-select)

" Add `:Format` command to format current buffer.
command! -nargs=0 Format :call CocActionAsync('format')

" Add `:Fold` command to fold current buffer.
command! -nargs=? Fold :call     CocAction('fold', <f-args>)

" Add `:OR` command for organize imports of the current buffer.
command! -nargs=0 OR   :call     CocActionAsync('runCommand', 'editor.action.organizeImport')

" Add (Neo)Vim's native statusline support.
" NOTE: Please see `:h coc-status` for integrations with external plugins that
" provide custom statusline: lightline.vim, vim-airline.
set statusline^=%{coc#status()}%{get(b:,'coc_current_function','')}
```

Comment: You are using two language server clients and two completion plugins as well as one very large go plugin. That and all the unrelated noise in your messy `vimrc` makes too many moving parts. Reduce your problem to something manageable/reproducible and use a more appropriate issue tracker/support channel. This place is about programming questions.

Comment: Thanks and sorry about my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for go I preferred [vim go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) this is the good plugging for go.

Comment: Thanks. I've started using it, really practical.